# Change Alt+Tab style in Lubuntu to show windows preview

Tags: lubuntu, task-management

Is there any way to change `Alt+Tab` style to include a preview (thumbnail) of windows?

Also, is it possible to jump into the list rather clicking Tab many times to reach the last windows in the list of `Alt+Tab`?

(I am using Lubuntu.)

Comment: I recommend you review your question, as this a forum for Ubuntu...

Comment: Lubuntu is a flavor of Ubuntu!

Comment: From past experience, it is best to only ask questions about Ubuntu... No matter what flavor... And especially do not spam with questions about other flavors... This is only meant to be helpful advice though.

Comment: I guess you mean Unity, right?